# Getting the EntityID of parent wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, multisite, shibboleth

I setup the WordPress Multisite as 123.abc.com. then I setup the Shibboleth authentication. Everything is fine. No issue. And then I setup the 456.abc.com as subdomain of 123.abc.com. Then when I tried to download the metadata of 456.abc.com as 456.abc.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata. I'm getting the entityID of 123.abc.com. I already restart the shibd and apache2. But I'm still getting the metadata file with the entityID of 123.abc.com. Do you guys have any idea?